# How to create subdomains for virtual machine on Azure

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have VM on myvmname.cloudapp.net. What I want is to create subdomain for this subdomain.myvmname.cloudapp.net. How can I do it?

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to do. Did you make any progress?

Comment: No, I still searching how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

OK anyway the best option is to go to your domain entity, and make a CNAME to point to to yourname.cloudapp.net and then on that VM route the subdomain to a folder.. That simple. So you can configure: subdomain.youdomain.com to yourname.cloudapp.net and then route internally to the folder you want.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, subdomains on x.cloudapp.net are not allowed at the moment.

Comment: Is this, still  true?